# child window with rich edit controls not loading on menu item click inside main window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to implement a chat window on a menu item click in the main window in win32. I have created a main window and am handling the chat window in the following way :

```
    int CALLBACK TextChat::TextChatDlgProc(  HWND hwndDlg,  UINT uMsg,  WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pdis;
    static HBRUSH hBrush;  
    static COLORREF GrayColor; 

    switch (uMsg) 
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) 
            {

            }
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            EndDialog(hwndDlg, 1);
            return true;           
            break;





        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {


            CentreWindow(hwndDlg);
            ShowWindow(hwndDlg,SW_SHOW);
            UpdateWindow(hwndDlg);
            return TRUE;

        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
int TextChat::DoDialog()
{

    //CreateWindowEx(


    return DialogBoxParam(this->m_pApp->m_instance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_CHAT_DIALOG), 
        NULL, (DLGPROC) TextChatDlgProc, (LONG) this->m_pCC);
}
```

And from my main window on menu item clic, i am doing it the following way :

```
case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
        {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case ID_TEXT_CHAT:
                    if(thisClass->m_pTextChat == NULL)
                        thisClass->m_pTextChat = new TextChat(thisClass->m_pApp,thisClass);
                    thisClass->m_pTextChat->DoDialog();
```

So i am using VS2008 and while debugging, the debugger goes inside TextChatDlgProc , but never goes inside WM_INITDIALOG and returns just like that. Hence, the chat window (resource IDD_CHAT_DIALOG) never get displayed. Any pointers towards resolving this problem is greatly appreciated. TIA

Regards,
grv

Comment: Can you look at the value of `uMsg` when it enters into `TextCharDlgProc`?

Comment: Anyway, my guess is that the creation of the dialog is failing, either because the template have some weirdness, or because it simply cannot be found in the indicated module.

Comment: @rodrigo: it starts with 48 to start with and then varies , but it never goes to WM_INITDIALOG, i am wondering where i might be going wrong

Comment: @rodrigo : I think i have figured out the problem , it is because of a rich edit text box i am using as the conversation area inside the chat window. The dialog works fine if i take out the rich edit box. Any suggestions !!

Comment: The question is misleading because the problem happens even before the menu click. Future visitors with the same problem will not see this answer because the title does not match the problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen : modified the question accordingly!!

Comment: Better, although the problem occurs even before the menu click. "the chat window (resource IDD_CHAT_DIALOG) never get displayed." The title says that the control doesn't load on a menu item click, but the menu item click never occurs at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say in a comment that the dialog has a rich edit control. That's the key!

You have to load the relevant library manually before these controls can be used. One of these:

```
LoadLibrary(TEXT("Msftedit.dll")); // for MSFTEDIT_CLASS
LoadLibrary(TEXT("Riched32.dll")); // for RICHEDIT_CLASS 3.2
LoadLibrary(TEXT("Riched20.dll")); // for RICHEDIT_CLASS 2.0
```

You can do that just once from `WinMain()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextChatDlgProc()` needs to <strike>call `DefWindowProc()` for [unhandled messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</strike> return FALSE for unhandled messages (default: switch case)

Comment: This is a `DlgProc`, not a `WndProc`. He should just return `FALSE` or `0` for unhandled messages.

Comment: The return type is wrong. It should be INT_PTR. Otherwise it will behave erratically when compiled for 64-bit.

Comment: The problem was due to the rich edit controls. Anyways thanks a lot for the suggestions. Very helpfull!!